# html2canvas Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas

I have a html tag canvas.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

I can draw on it successfully, and it looks really good, as i wanted to be.
The problem is on the conversion to png.I use html2canvas for that with Canvas2Image. The html2canvas consoles logs an error: 
Uncaught (in promise) undefined.
Canvas2Image console logs Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0. I can understand the error very well, the canvas has width and height != 0. Any ideas?

---

html2canvas code:

```
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('myCanvas')).then(canvas9 => {

    var theimage9 = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas9);
    var imageData9 = $(theimage9).attr('src');


    console.log(imageData9);
  });
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? @Cache

Answer (score 2):

Tested Chrome, Firefox ok, IE 11 needs adding 2 extra js library to support promise.

```js
function takeSnapShot() {
 html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(function(canvas9) {
  var theimage9 = canvas9.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.querySelector("#theimage9").src = theimage9; 
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Capture" onclick="takeSnapShot()"/>
<img id="theimage9" border="0" />
```

Answer (score -1):

[html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) is used for converting html code into a canvas view. If I am understanding correctly, you just want to get an image from the canvas so `html2canvas` is not needed. Simply just use `Canvas2Image` on it's own.

Example (blue is the image, red is the canvas):

```js
// Example canvas with circle
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();


var image = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(c); // Returns HTMLImageElement 

$("#canvasImg").attr('src', image.src); // Set the src of our output image to the src of the HTMLImageElement
```

```html
<!-- Output -->
<img id="canvasImg" src="" style="border:2px solid blue;">

<!-- Input -->
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:2px solid red;"></canvas>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvas2image@1.0.5/canvas2image.min.js"></script>
```